Is it possible to have a FullCalendar dayGridYear to span across the year break
For example, if I have the following:
visibleRange: {
        start: '2024-12-23',
        end: '2025-01-19'
        },   
validRange: {
        start: '2024-12-23',
        end: '2025-01-19'
        }

Then the dayGridYear only shows Dec 23 - Jan 5.  For other times of the year, this kind of range of dates is not an issue, it appears to be a problem because it is spanning across the year.
I did a search, and couldn't find this documented as an issue anywhere.

I was able to resolve this by switching for dayGridYear to just dayGrid.

For anyone reading this and wondering why, it's fairly simple: If you specify dayGridYear, the Year gives the view a fixed duration (of 1 year, obviously). Therefore, fullCalendar ignores any visibleRange options specified, because specifying a date range like that contradicts the Year instruction already given. And obviously if you then remove the Year and just specify that the view is a dayGrid, with no particular fixed duration, you can then use visibleRange to set a custom duration for the view. Hope that helps.
